# C# methods don't follow order

Tags: c#, methods

I have to do a 10 question quiz, 5 question true or false and 5 question multiple choice. This needs to be accomplished using methods. The problem that I'm having is that the program is not executing in order, instead of doing the "Class User" first, "Class Quiz" second, and "Class Score" third. It is only doing "Class Quiz" and closes out. Also, the program shows no errors.

```
class User
{
    internal string name;

    public static void Name(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Aeronautical Knowledge Quiz.");
        Console.WriteLine("This Quiz consists of 10 questions.");
        Console.WriteLine("5 True or False and 5 Multiple choice.");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name (last, first) and press ENTER.");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Welcom to the Aeronautical Knowledge Quiz " + name + "!");
        Console.WriteLine("NOTE: This quiz is case sensitive.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to begin the quiz.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

    }

}
class Quiz
{
    internal string correctAnswer;
    internal string qcounter;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] questions = { "The fuselage is the center structure of an aircraft and provides the connection for the wings and tail. (True or False)?",
            "Rolling is the action on the lateral axis of an aircraft. (True or False)?",
            "Drag is the name of the force that resists movement of an aircraft through the air. (True or False)?",
            "Flaps are attached to the trailing edge of a wing structure and only increases drag. (True or False)?",
            "Powerplant or engine, produces thrust to propel an aircraft. (True or False)?",
            "Which of the following are part of an aircraft primary flight controls? a.Aileron. b.Rudder. c.Elevators. d. All the above.",
            "The Fuel-air control unit of a reciprocating engine? a.Sends fuel to the piston chamber. b.Sends air to the piston chamber. c.Controls the mixture of air and fuel. d.Meters the quantity of fuel.",
            "Which of the following is the main source of electrical power when starting an aircraft? a.Primary Bus. b.Avionics Bus. c.Battery. d.GPU (ground power unit)",
            "The reservoir of a hydraulic system is used for? a.Store and collect fluid from a hydraulic system. b.Lubricate components when needed. c.Keep the fluid clean. d.All the above.",
            "Flying into fog can create. a.Narrows the runway. b.An aircraft to stall. c.An illusion of pitching up. d.A stressful environment for the Pilot and Co-pilot." };

        string[] answers = { "True", "True", "True", "False", "True", "d", "c", "c", "a", "c" };
        string studentAnswer;
        float correctAnswer = 0;
        float qcounter = 0;
        var questionNum = 0;
        var answerNum = 0;
        while (questionNum < questions.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(questions[questionNum], 10, 30);
            studentAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (studentAnswer == answers[answerNum])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
                questionNum++;
                answerNum++;
                correctAnswer++;
                qcounter++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect.");
                questionNum++;
                answerNum++;
                qcounter++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER for Next question.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();

        }
    }

}

class Score
{
    static void Value(string[] args)
    {
        User n = new User();
        Quiz m = new Quiz();
        Console.WriteLine(n.name + ", Your final score is: " + m.correctAnswer + "/" + m.qcounter + ".");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to EXIT");

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are never calling the static methods of the other 2 classes, why would you expect them to execute?

Comment: You seem to assume that in C# methods are loaded and executed like in JavaScript. No this is not the case. Programs starts with the class that contain the Main function and then you should call yourself the methods you want to execute and define the order of execution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only part that's executed is the `Main` static method. If you want to execute other methods, you should call them explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

It's because in project properties the startup method is Quiz's main function.
You need to change the startup method from here.
[image]

Or it would be better if you create project from scratch and use standard "Program" class and it's "Main" method for startup and then add User, Quiz and Score classes.

Comment: Changing the startup method would not solve OPs issue at all, at least 2 methods would never be called in the code. And there's no need to start again from scratch, there is nothing special about the default `Program` class